# RoR - проблема с командой "rake db:migrate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rake db:migrate
```

дает ошибку:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

куда копать?

Окружение:

- Windows 10
- RubyMine 2016
- все гемы поставились удачно. (bundle install работает)

Comment: Это всё сообщение об ошибке? И повторю совет, который давал многим: работайте с RoR в Unix-подобных ОС, хотя бы в виртуалках, даже при таком раскладе сэкономите кучу времени.

Comment: а если просто запустить `rake` без параметров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось тривиальным:

```
rails db:migrate
```

а я в полусне просто не увидел даного решения на странице с ошибкой...

Comment: А, так у вас ещё и Rails 5? :D

Comment: А лучше учится на 4ке?

Comment: Учиться лучше на том, на чём у вас учебные материалы построены.

Answer (score -1):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Это из-за того что gem ruby make не установлен. Решил вот так:

```
gem install rake
```

Comment: Нет, не надо так делать. Устанавливать зависимости нужно через `bundler`, командой `bundle` или `bundle install`. И команда `rails new` делает это самостоятельно после сборки скелета приложения, устанавливая в том числе `rake`. А ставить каждый гем отдельной командой долго и бессмысленно.

Comment: Вы конечно правы, но вот я к примеру создавал новый проект через     `rails new` и гем ruby make не установился. Я мог делать все тоже самое просто меняя команду`rake` на `rails`, а в туториалах везде приводится `rake`. Как я понял в 5 версии rails что то изменилось касательно ruby make. Вопрос нужен ли вообще этот гем в 5 рельсах? А если я например хочу добавить новый гем в проект то необходимо отредактировать gemfile и запустить снова bundle install?

Comment: @newbie_rails вы вообще не должны задаваться этим вопросом, у вас в гемфайле должно быть то, чем вы непосредственно пользуетесь, а Bundler доставит то, что для них необходимо. Да, процедура добавления гема верная. Rake в зависимостях Rails, так что Bundler не мог успешно завершиться, не установив его.